# is there a name for this conditional-checking technique?

Tags: terminology

so, theres a technique I use in a fair amount of programming languages and projects; and I'm wondering if it has a general, language-agnostic "official" term to describe it.

basically, I nicknamed it "trip switch checking." Its where if you need to check that several variables have specific values, possibly of different types, you first set a boolean to "false" and then in either a loop or several if statements, you check what you need to by setting the boolean to true if any of the other variables don't meet your requirements.

I call it trip-switching because the boolean remains false if the "switch" isn't "tripped," using an analogy from a common safety mechanism on industrial machinery where if something moves too far or gets too close or etc. a physical switch is actually bumped into and it shuts the whole thing down. the idea is not to switch it back off until the obstruction is cleared- the machine cant turn itself back on automatically.

pseudocode example, a function that returns true if the trip switch wasn't hit:

```
function tripswitchcheck()
{
  boolean tripswitch = false

  if(idontnwantthis == true)
  {
     tripswitch = true
  }
  if(iwantthis == false)
  {
     tripswitch = true
  }
  //...etc...basically do stuff to check stuff. if any values are undesired, true the tripswitch.

  return !tripswitch
}
```

It may be bad practice depending on the language and nature of the project, but it works, and that's outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: I call it "setting a flag". I don't know if there is a better name. Creating your own name works as well. I don't see anything wrong with calling it "trip-switching".

Comment: If you choose to use your nickname in comments or documentation, make sure to define what it means. Otherwise the next person to read your code or document will be very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why would you not just have a positive flag in that example:

```
function tripswitchcheck()
{
  boolean success = true;

  if(idontnwantthis == true)
  {
     success = false;
  }
  if(iwantthis == false)
  {
     success = false;
  }
  //...etc...basically do stuff to check stuff. if any values are undesired, falsify success

  return success
}
```

Secondly, why check the conditions if you already know you have failure. Say that we don't have a forward goto in the language, or `else`, or early returns (or we don't want to return because something else is done based on the `success` flag before returning):

```
function tripswitchcheck()
{
  boolean success = true;

  if(idontnwantthis == true)
  {
     success = false;
  }
  if(success && iwantthis == false)  // if success is false, fall through
  {
     success = false;
  }
  if(success && !othercondition())   // likewise
  {
     success = false;
  }
  //...etc...

  return success
}
```

There are reasons not to use `else` if some of the conditions make use of earlier results.

Anyway, this just comes from basic logic and scientific reasoning: we have a hypothesis and look for reasons why it is not true.

The name for it is perhaps "single exit rule" and such: the function exits through a single return statement.

Comment: *why would you not just have a positive flag in that example*  Perhaps I'm just pessimistic by nature, but I find "it succeeded until I tell you it failed" to be unfounded optimism; I prefer "it has not succeeded until I tell you it has".  So, "success" is initialized false.  And if I forget to write a "success = true" I'll likely find out faster than if I forget a "success = false".

Comment: @accessviolation But then you express sudden optimism in the inverted `return` statement: `return !failed`: if it hasn't failed, it must have succeeded. You're still assuming success, unless a true-means-failed flag indicates otherwise.  To actually change the semantics, your individual tests have to look for success. If you're testing for failure and setting "failed = true", you're testing for failure against a background assumption of success, regardless of the polarity of the flag.

Comment: @Kaz my example uses the tripswitch condition for failure, not success. if its true, that means failure, otherwise not- hence the inversion. I am marking this as the answer despite the programming advice being out of the question's scope, because you answered anyways when you said "it might be called the single exit rule." that said- the polarity doesn't matter as long as you check the right state for your purposes. this could be easily written both ways and have the same result.

Comment: @kaz - not at all. ''success' is initialized to false and stays false until the operation has definitively succeeded.